# Raspberry Pi Hexapod 18DOF, Best servo control board?

Tags: mobile-robot, raspberry-pi, servomotor, rcservo, hexapod

Recently I've bought a [hexapod kit](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/231583577928) and 18 TowerPro MG995 servos.

My objective is to apply also the Pi camera, sensors and perhaps a claw...
So I've been researching and I haven't found a clear answer when comes to the servo control board.

Which servo controller board shall I choose to complete my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servo's are controlled by Pulse Width Modulation (PWM) so you need a PWM controller that has enough pins and power to drive Servos. I'd go with 2 of [Adafruit's I2C-based controller](https://www.adafruit.com/products/815) but Pololu has a [USB one](https://www.pololu.com/product/1354) that is rather popular.